# In vs on, internet language

Tags: prepositions

Please help me clarifying the use of IN Vs ON when using it in websites.

I have an online account and I was informed that it is incorrect to use "IN" when referring to the contents of my account. I was told to always use "ON" if it it something to do with the internet.

Instead of "In your Google account" it should be "ON your Google account".

Comment: Accounts existed long before the internet, and are basically recepticles for information etc. As they are recepticles you put items *in* your account.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what information you are referring to and what the account accounts.

The information that is accounted is referred to as **in** your account, whereas the meta data about your account is referred to as **on** your account.

For instance, you may have a lot of email **in** your account, and a strange name **on** your account. It is the same as in the bank, you have money **in** the bank account, but your name **on** the account.

The only thing special with the internet and the use of *in/on* is that in many phrases about the internet the noun refers to the 'server', and stuff always happen **on** the server, not *in*